# User-defined functions in BigQuery used column name with dot

Tags: javascript, sql, google-bigquery

I need to create my custom ([user defined](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions)) JS function in **BigQuery**. First, I want to create simple "starter" based on Google example, but in my situation I need to use data from column with dots in name (eg. "hits.item.transactionId") and this returns error.

My **user-defined function** (code in *UDF Editor*):

```
function passthroughExample(row, emit) {
  emit({outputA: row.fullVisitorId, outputB: row.transactionId});
}

bigquery.defineFunction(
  'passthrough',
  ['fullVisitorId', 'transactionId'],
  [{'name': 'outputA', 'type': 'string'},
   {'name': 'outputB', 'type': 'string'}],
  passthroughExample
);
```

My **SQL** Select used my passthroughExample() function:

```
SELECT
  outputA, outputB
FROM
  (passthrough(SELECT fullVisitorId, hits.item.transactionId AS transactionId FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE( [00000000.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01'), TIMESTAMP('2016-01-05') )))
```

---

I got message:

ERROR: **Unsupported alias: unable to access field hits.item.transactionId as transactionId**

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use standard SQL instead of legacy SQL for this purpose. You can read about user defined functions in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions). In your case, you would want something like this:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION passthrough(fullVisitorId INT64, transactionId STRING)
RETURNS STRUCT<outputA INT64, outputB STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
var res = new Object();
res.outputA = fullVisitorId;
res.outputB = transactionId;
return res;
""";

SELECT passthrough(hit.item.fullVisitorId, transactionId).*
FROM `your_dataset.ga_sessions_*`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hit
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-05';
```

Some of the differences between user defined functions in legacy versus standard SQL are explained in [the migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#functions_in_the_query_text).

Answer (score 0):

Try with the alias in the UDF:

```
bigquery.defineFunction(
  'passthrough',
  ['fullVisitorId', 'hits.item.transactionId'],
  [{'name': 'outputA', 'type': 'string'},
   {'name': 'outputB', 'type': 'string'}],
  passthroughExample
);
```

And no alias in the query:

```
SELECT
  outputA, outputB
FROM
  (passthrough(SELECT fullVisitorId, hits.item.transactionId FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE( [00000000.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01'), TIMESTAMP('2016-01-05') )))
```

Comment: I checked. Name of alias does not matter. Error message is always the same.